# lnner product ....

Tags: linear-algebra

If f(x)f(x) and g(x)g(x) are arbitrary polynomials of degree at most 2,

then the mapping______

⟨f,g⟩=f(−1)g(−1)+f(0)g(0)+f(2)g(2)

⟨f,g⟩=f(−1)g(−1)+f(0)g(0)+f(2)g(2)____
defines an inner product in P2.
______between f(x) and g(x) for
f(x)=2x^2+5x+8    and  g(x)=4x^2−6x−8.

For this question, the question asks to find ∥f∥.
As what I attempt, the answer is \sqrt{93} which is incorrect. The way I do it is \sqrt{4+25+64}. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you doing $⟨f,f⟩$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(-1)=5,f(0)=8$ and $f(2)=26.$ Thus

$$\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}=\sqrt{5^2+8^2+26^2}. $$

Comment: The last one should be  f(5) = 26, but I understand how to do it now.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @sam Ups. You're rigtht. It must be $f(2)=26.$